# MongoDb bulk operation get id

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bulkinsert, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I want to perform bulk operation via MongoDb. How to get array of Ids that will be returned after it?

Can i perform single-operation insert faster without using bulk ? Can you advise me some other approach ?
I'm using `C# mongoDb driver 2.0` and `MongoDb v. 3.0.2`

update:
I found the following solution - save maximum `ObjectId` of mongo collection,

```
db.col.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

and do the same after insert
So we will get the range of inserted documents, does it make a sense?

Comment: Getting the ids from the db after the operations will work, but it's less efficient since the ids are already in the driver.

Comment: `ObjectId`s don't increase monotonously, so your plan doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert items in bulk using the new driver with `InsertManyAsync`. If you want the Ids that the driver generated for these items you can simply get them out of the items themselves after they are inserted. For example:

```
Hamster[] hamsters = { new Hamster { Name = "Vaska" }, new Hamster { Name = "Petzka" } };
await collection.InsertManyAsync(hamsters);
var insertedIDs = hamsters.Select(_ => _.Id);
```